# "Accept change" and "reject change" keyboard shortcuts in Google Docs

Tags: google-docs, keyboard-shortcuts, collaboration

Do these not exist?  I found it *so* handy using Lyx for a project recently, to be able to quickly keyboard-navigate and accept/reject, with no mouse involvement.  For one thing, Google Docs' navigation here is a bit cumbersome (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>,<kbd>C</kbd>, really?), but then I could not find any way to accept/reject.

Does everyone do such repetitive work all with the mouse, or is there some solution or plugin to enable a keyboard-centric workflow here?